# divide div into equal parts by div

Tags: html, css

the task is to make a separated progressbar, so i need to divide div 1-2-3-4-...n times. here is a code:

```
.progress {
    width:  99%;
    height: 15px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.progress .danger {
    background-color: #dd514c;
}
.progress .warning {
    background: #ffaf4b;
}
.progress .success {
    background-color: #5eb95e;
}
.wrapper {
    border-left: 1px solid #7e7d7d;
}
.progress div {
    float: left;
}
<div class="progress">
    <div class="wrapper" style="width: 33%;">
        <div class="danger" style="width: 20%;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper" style="width: 33%;">
        <div class="warning" style="width: 20%;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper" style="width: 33%;">
        <div class="success" style="width: 100%;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

but after third div (wrapper->success) there is a some whitespace (above 5 percents). how to prevent it?
my task is also to create a script for generating this progressbat, so here might be 3 part, 2 pars or even 5 parts, and the solution should be universal.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what this progress bar means, but about your question about some whitespace: 33+33+33 = 99 (not 100), so this is why you see this whitespace. You can try to set each width to 33.333% for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for starters, the wrapping element `.progress` has a width value set to `99%` - why? Then there's 1% missing naturally missing since you only use `width: 33%` for the child elements.

It would seem like you set the parent to `width: 99%` since the `.wrapper` elements together take up 99% of the available space. I can see your thinking but that's not how CSS works.

When you declare a percentage width of something, that percentage is always calculated in relation to the element's parent width. So the `.wrapper` has 33% of the width of `.progress`, while `.progress` has 99% of the width of its parent, whatever it might be.

Change your CSS accordingly:

```
.progress {
    width: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 33.333%; /* remove the inline CSS and use this instead */
}
```

I also like to use `float: right` on the *last* child in a row of floated elements. This is to compensate for potential rounding problems when [sub-pixels](http://ejohn.org/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/) occur, moving white space on the right edge of the element to the left, making it harder to notice.

There's also one other issue in your CSS; that is the `border` on `.wrapper`. `Border` and `padding`-value are added ontop of width, so your `.wrapper` elements are actually 33% wide *plus* 1px each from the border. This does most likely put you over 100% width if you set their width to 33.333% as suggested above, breaking your layout.

One way to handle this is to simply move the border to another child element (so that the border is set to your classes `.danger`, `.warning` and `.success` instead), or to decrease the width from 33.333% to something lower (and perhaps float the last child to the right to "hide" the white space).

However the method I prefer for handling this issue is to change the `box-sizing` of the element(s) to `border-box`. I won't go into detail on this here and now, but it basically changes how an element's size is calculated, adding borders and paddings to the inside of the element rather than the outside. Read about it [here](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/), or [here](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/).